# What does the condition "VSDFXAvailable" mean? (Why does my custom .net-Setup fail?)

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer

In visual studio 2010 I have setup a Project "Visual Studio Installer" it includes a custom action.

On my development machine the installer works as intended.

On two test machines (windows 7 with the .net 4.0 installed) the installation fails.

The setup is requesting/attempting the installation of the .net 4.0 framework (which is already there).

using msiexec installer.msi /L*V test.log I produced a detailed log, excerpt below.

This leads me to believe my problem is related to the failed evaluation of the launch condition

> VSDFXAvailable

With google I find only reference to pasted log files.

What it this condition is even about?
Can somebody have a look at the log file and confirm that this is causing the error?

Thanks!

The complete log is here: http://codetidy.com/359

```
Action start 17:19:49: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions.
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:377] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: Custom Action is starting...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:378] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:378] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: Enumerating table using SQL statement: 'SELECT * FROM `_VsdLaunchCondition`'
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:379] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: Calling MsiGetActiveDatabase...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:379] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: MsiDatabaseOpenViewW - Prepare Database to view table...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:380] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: TMsiViewExecute - Open Database view on table...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:380] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: Checking a launch condition...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:381] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: Getting the condition to evaluate...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:381] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:381] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '1'...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:382] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: Evaluating condition 'VSDFXAvailable'...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:382] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: RESULT:    Condition is false.
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:382] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:383] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '2'...
This setup requires the .NET Framework version 4.0.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:384] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting Property Value...
MSI (s) (24!FC) [17:19:49:384]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding HideFatalErrorForm property. Its value is 'TRUE'.
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:384] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting property 'HideFatalErrorForm' to 'TRUE'.
ERROR  : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:385] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: Custom Action failed with code: '1603'
INFO   : [01/01/2011 17:19:49:385] [VsdLaunchConditions                   ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '1603'
CustomAction VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 17:19:49: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 17:19:49: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property seems to be used by a .NET Framework launch conditions. Try checking RegLocator table in your MSI to see if the launch condition uses a Windows Installer search. If it does, check if the target registry entry exists on your machine.

Also, make sure that the .NET Framework installation matches your package platform. For example, a 32-bit installer will most likely not detect a 64-bit .NET Framework.

Comment: I checked the MSI using Orca but the RegLocator Table is empty. I believe to have Windows 32 bit on all machines, but I will double check.

Comment: I changed the installer to require ".net frame work 4.0" instead of ".net framework 4.0 Client Profile"